# How to get the formula cell value(data) using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am using Apache poi3.5 and java
1.6 for my application. here, i have one problem using formula...

my Cell has formula(sheet2!C10) and the data inside this cell is String type...How to access that cell also want to display the formula.

my Cell has formula(sheet2!C11) and the data inside this cell is number type...How to access that cell also want to display the formula.

my Cell has formula(sheet2!C10) and the data inside this cell is Date type...How to access that cell and also want to display the formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Formula Cell value :" + org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator));
```

it will return the formula cell value as a string...

Answer (score 8):

For any formula cell, using poi3.8.

```
Workbook xlsWorkbook = null;
Cell cell = null;

FormulaEvaluator formulaEval = xlsWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
String value=formulaEval.evaluate(cell).formatAsString();
```